# ¿Cómo Mostrar la ActionBar, ToolBar por encima de los otros controles en Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy creando un visualizador de imagenes y quiero que la `ActionBar` se visualize por encima de la imagen y de forma semitransparente.

Ahora lo soluciono con un `frameLayout` asignando un color `#88676767` a la `toolbar`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.testtransitions.PhotoViewActivity">

    <com.allenxuan.xuanyihuang.xuanimageview.XuanImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:AutoRotateCategory="2"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy_image" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#88676767"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</FrameLayout>
```

pero busando un poco he visto que tambien se puede realizar con la propiedad `windowActionBarOverlay` en `styles.xml`, no me ha quedado claro, si es para la vieja `ActionBar` ya que parte de `api11`o bien con MaterialDesign no se establece etc...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

entiendo que buscas algo asi
[image]

para ello puedes usar la propiedad `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`
a mi me funciona y se vera el fondo que tengas en tu activity, espero te ayude, esto lo probe con la **toolbar**, no la **action bar**